# Find All References (Shift+F12) with css

Tags: css, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using SCSS and web technologies and was hoping to find out where a CSS class or id was being used; for all the uses. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I know you can see where the properties and methods are being used, but was wondering if I could use the same tactic for CSS and even javascript. Would I need another IDE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can always use firbug. It allows you to inspect and modify html styles and a whole lot more
 here is the link.

http://getfirebug.com/